# How to monitor HDD temperatures in HW RAID

Tags: linux, raid, monitoring

I have 4 disks in 2 RAID1 mirrors on a Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array. The OS is Ubuntu 10.04, cciss driver - so it's a hardware RAID
We recently moved our office and the servers are in less then perfect conditions (no a/c, and with the summer temperatures, the fans work a lot).

Is there a way to monitor the temperatures or any other parameters on the disks/array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the HP SmartArrays I've worked on have included temperature probes.

How specifically, you would access yours might depend on the specific model you have, and it may be different on Linux, but the ACU [Array Configuration Utility] is should be accessible online.  Here's [the link to a manual](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00729544/c00729544.pdf) for one of the arrays I admin.  Search HP's site for the manual specific to yours.

> Launching ACU on a local server
>   Linux OS
>
> 1: From any command prompt, enter one of the following:
>
> o For local mode, enter: cpqauxe-nosmh
>
> o For remote mode, enter: cpqacuxe-R
>
> ACU launches in a browser (Mozilla Firefox).
>
> 2: For a list of options, enter the following:
>
> cpqacuxe-h

And, if you head down to page 54, there's an explanation of the "show" command, and the example output contains readings from the temperature probes on the array.

Comment: now I have to work out on how to avoid Firefox, the server is headless :)

Answer (score 1):

If the host connected to the smartarray is an HP, you can use the proliant support pack with check_hpasm for nagios to monitor the various parts of the hardware, including things like temperature.

http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/nagios/check_hpasm/